# Rails migrate a column to an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, relationship

I have a rails application with a postgres db. I started with a rails model Ticket that kept track of the Event the ticket has access to, but multiple tickets can be purchased at one time. So now I have this:

```
Ticket
    belongs_to :purchase

Event
    belongs_to :purchase

Purchase
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :events
```

I'd like to use a migration wherever a ticket does not have a purchase, create a purchase and set its ticket_id to the ticket, set its event_id to the ticket's event_id, set the ticket's event_id to nil, then drop event_id from ticket.

Thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: This type of logic can go into your controller when you create your ticket.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but what do I do about the existing tickets?

Comment: You can run a rake (which is pretty much a script) that will update your existing tickets to match your desired requirements. You'd have to write this script, of course.

Comment: Ah, so maybe I'm trying to fit a square peg into a round hole then.

Comment: Yes, you no longer have to run any migrations if your tables are set up correctly. At this point, it is mostly controller logic (to make sure new tickets create new purchases with correct values) and running a rake (to fix old tickets that were created from old logic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to generate a rake task in Rails: http://railsguides.net/2012/03/14/how-to-generate-rake-task/

Your rake task to update the historic records should look something like this:

```
# lib/tasks/something.rake
desc "Update old stuff"
task :my_task1 => :environment do
  tickets = Ticket.where("purchase_id IS NULL")
  tickets.each do |ticket|
    ticket.purchase.create!([attributes])
    ...[more stuff]...
  end
end
```

Run the rake task on the command like:

```
$ bundle exec rake my_task1
```

I was not able to follow the logic of your application 100%, but hopefully this will set you in the right direction.